# Room error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

[image]

I made a screen like the image.

As you can see, the `Set information items` are in the `red box`.

I want to store these data in `Room DB`.

The `red box` is composed of `Workout Class`, and the `blue box` (`WorkoutSetInfo class`) is included in it.

I just want to get a list of `set information` from Room.

But I wrote a query to get a list of `set information`,
I got the following error:

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id,set,weight,reps] in com.example.lightweight.data.db.entity.WorkoutSetInfo even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [sets]
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.example.lightweight.data.db.entity.WorkoutSetInfo>> getWorkoutSetInfoList()
```

There have been several similar questions to mine, but I still haven't been able to solve them. How can I get only the list of set information?

---

**WorkoutSetInfo**

```
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), // For comparison in DiffUtil.
    val set: Int,
    val weight: String = "",
    val reps: String = ""
)
```

**Workout**

```
@Entity
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val title: String = "",
    val unit: String = "kg",
    val memo: String = "",
    var sets: List<WorkoutSetInfo> = emptyList()
)
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {
    @Query("SELECT sets FROM Workout")
    fun getWorkoutSetInfoList() : LiveData<List<WorkoutSetInfo>>

    @Insert
    fun insert(workout: Workout)
}
```

**Repository**

```
class WorkoutRepository(private val workoutDao : WorkoutDao, title: String) {
    val workout = Workout(0, title)
    var setInfoList : ArrayList<WorkoutSetInfo> = arrayListOf()
    
    val _items: LiveData<List<WorkoutSetInfo>> = workoutDao.getWorkoutSetInfoList()

    fun add(item: WorkoutSetInfo) {
        setInfoList.add(item)
        workout.sets = setInfoList

        workoutDao.insert(workout)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class DetailViewModel(application: Application, title: String) : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: WorkoutRepository

    private lateinit var _items: LiveData<List<WorkoutSetInfo>>
    val items = _items
    private val list: List<WorkoutSetInfo>
        get() = _items.value ?: emptyList()

    init {
        val workoutDao = DetailDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.workoutDao()
        repository = WorkoutRepository(workoutDao, title)
        _items = repository._items
    }

    fun addDetail() {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val item = WorkoutSetInfo(set = list.size+1)
            repository.add(item)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED**

```
class Converter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJson(value: List<WorkoutSetInfo>) : String {
        return Gson().toJson(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToList(value: String) : List<WorkoutSetInfo> {
        return Gson().fromJson(value, Array<WorkoutSetInfo>::class.java).toList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to save a list of complex object in a column.  Room does not know how to save that.

`var sets: List<WorkoutSetInfo> = emptyList()` <-- this is complex

Remember room is just sqlite underneath and your entities represent tables.  Sqlite recognizes basic types but storing a list of complex objects is not something it can do by default. You can explore [TypeConverters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters) as a solution if you want to save this object in the same table.

See below for a relational solution that utilizes separate tables:

What you are looking for here is a [one-to-many](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) relation.  A single `Workout` can have one or more `WorkoutSetInfo`

In the world of relational databases, you can represent this by having a separate table for `WorkoutSetInfo` and use the id from `id` of the work out to create a relation.

```
@Entity
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), // For comparison in DiffUtil.
    val set: Int,
    val weight: String = "",
    val reps: String = "",
    val workoutId: String // <-- this is the id of the workout that this set is associated with
)
```

Once you have that you can either write a join query or use a data object to query as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many)

You can have something like this:

```
data class WorkoutWithSets(
    @Embedded val workout: Workout,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "workoutId"
    )
    val sets: List<WorkoutSetInfo>
)
```

And use something like this to query it

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Workout WHERE id = :workoutId")
    fun getWorkoutWithSets(workoutId: String) : LiveData<WorkoutWithSets>
```

This will give the workout for the given id along with all the sets that match that workout id in the set table.

Comment: Are you saying that there should be two `tables` of `Workout` and `WorkoutSetInfo` for this, rather than just using one table called `Workout`?

Comment: Yes, `WorkoutSetInfo` should be its own table and should contain a column for workout id.  Then in your query you would use the workoutId column to get all of the `WorkoutSetInfo` associated with a given workout.

Comment: Then, two tables, `Workout` and `WorkoutSetInfo`, should exist, `WorkoutSetInfo` should contain `Workout Id`, and `WorkoutSetInfo Table` should be accessed with `Workout Id`, right?

Comment: Yes, if you look at my example query above, it'll give you what you need.  Also, make sure that `WorkoutSetInfo` is an Entity (also shown in the answer) which will tell Room to create a table for it.

Comment: great. But I have a question.

The link you replied to showed a `one-to-many relationship`.

But since it is `WorkoutSetInfo` for `Workout`, shouldn't it be a `one-to-one` relationship?
(`one Workout table` and `one WorkoutSetInfo table`)

Comment: It's one `WorkoutSetInfo` table but that table may contain multiple entries for a single workout.  The one thing that didn't mention is that you'll have to make sure whenever you insert in your workout table you also insert the corresponding workout sessions in your `WorkoutSetInfo` table

Comment: Was the relationship based on a `tuple` rather than a `table-to-table`?
And I didn't understand correctly that every time I insert it into the `workout table`, I need to insert the `workout session` into the `WorkoutSetInfo table` as well.
Are you saying that when inserting a tuple into `Workout`, at least `one tuple` must also be inserted into `WorkoutSetInfo`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243663/discussion-between-naveed-and-ybybyb).

Comment: ok..i left an additional chat

Comment: Ok.. But I'm already using TypeConverter and I'm getting an error. I don't know where the problem is..

Comment: I would recommend asking another question about TypeConverter and list specifically, as I may not have time to follow up on this.

Answer (score 1):

currently your posted error is telling that set is not found in selection

```
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), // For comparison in DiffUtil.
    val set: Int,//Add Any value or make it nullable here for get temp rid of this error
    val weight: String = "",
    val reps: String = ""
)
```

but As Naveeds Answer, you have to use typeConvertor or solve this problem with relational database type
without implementing this typeconvertor or relational structure room will give you error

Comment: I have already implemented `TypeConverter` (see `update`)
I got this error while creating a `TypeConverter`.

By the way, are you saying that you can create a `table` without using a `TypeConverter`?

Comment: TypeConverter Or Two Table is options for your case. Can I know have you got same error after implementation of TypeConverter? Have you tried to make set nullable ?

Comment: Updated the `TypeConverter` class to the original poster. I was using TypeConverter and got an error.

And I have no intention of setting `set` to `null`.